# Increase the size of the image in the expanded QComboBox list

Tags: pyqt5, size, qcombobox, qpixmap, qicon

there is a small piece of program code. As it has a Combobox that contains a drop-down list.
Please help with 2 questions:

1. how not to display the first picture in the expanded list? that is, you need the first picture to be visible when the list is not disclosed.
2. how do I increase the size of 2 and 3 images (which are in the drop-down list), for example, by 2 times?

---

Pictures are not attached, you can attach any other
__

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *     
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
import sys


app = QApplication([])
tab = QTabWidget()
tab.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 1000)


class Tabs_tools(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.combo_box = QComboBox()
        self.combo_box.setStyleSheet("QComboBox::drop-down {""width: 0px;" "border: 0px;" "}")
        self.combo_box.setFixedSize(120, 120)
        self.combo_box.setIconSize(QSize(120, 120))     
        self.combo_box.setView(QListView())
        self.combo_box.view().setRowHidden(0, True)
        self.combo_box.view().setFixedSize(400, 220)

        icon1 = QIcon('App_DB/Images/Load_data.png')
        icon2 = QIcon(QPixmap('App_DB/Images/Load_data_file.png').scaled(QSize(11000, 11000)))
        icon3 = QIcon(QPixmap('App_DB/Images/Load_data_file.png').scaled(QSize(110, 110)))

        self.combo_box.addItem(icon1, '')
        self.combo_box.addItem(icon2, 'From the file')
        self.combo_box.addItem(icon3, 'From the folder')

        self.combo_box.activated[str].connect(self.get_FileNames)
        
        # 
        grid_for_tab_Gemeral = QGridLayout()
        grid_for_tab_Gemeral.setColumnStretch(0, 0)
        grid_for_tab_Gemeral.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)

        grid_for_tab_Gemeral.addWidget(self.combo_box, 0, 0)

        group_box = QGroupBox()
        group_box.setLayout(grid_for_tab_Gemeral)

        # 
        self.tab = QTabWidget()
        self.tab.setFixedSize(1800, 180)
        self.tab.setContentsMargins(-100, 0, 0, 0)

        self.tab.addTab(group_box, 'Main')
        self.tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'Сonvert data')
        self.tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'Add column')

        self.tab.setStyleSheet(
            """QTabBar::tab {
                border: 1px solid #C4C4C3;
                padding: 10px;}""")

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setColumnStretch(0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.tab, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def get_FileNames(self, text):
        file_paths = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()[0]

        if file_paths:
            if text == 'From the file"':
                self.processing_excel()

    def processing_excel(self):
        print('f')       


grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
grid.setColumnStretch(1, 0)
grid.setRowStretch(4, 4)
grid.addWidget(Tabs_tools(), 0, 0)
tab.setLayout(grid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tab.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I read the documentation and did not find the answer, I asked a chatGPT question, but he also did not give the correct code

I need this as in the picture:

[image]

Comment: It seems like you don't really need a combobox, but a popup menu with items that have icons at different sizes, is it right?

Comment: @musicamante, yes, that's right

Comment: @musicamante, in my question, I added a link picture, which shows how I need

Comment: For future reference, ensure that you ask the correct question: you want to create a custom menu, which is completely different than a combo box both in behavior and purpose. It seems like you're trying to recreate a "Ribbon" interface, which is doable in Qt but also very, very difficult. One of the main problems is that a proper implementation should follow the standard QAction behavior, meaning that a QMenu must be used, and the only way to achieve this is by using a custom QWidgetAction with careful QStyle querying for proper object geometries and consistent painting results.

Comment: Note that the above is fundamentally mandatory, you cannot just use a basic QWidget for the action, otherwise you'll end up with problems sooner or later, so you need to do proper research about QAction, QMenu, QStyle and also user event management. I don't want to be rude, but from what from your code (including that of your other question) it seems clear that you need to be far more experienced in order to do all this: your codes have **a lot** of important issues that need to be resolved and properly understood before being *able* to try and achieve such a complex behavior.